# How to upload the image to server using json link in android?

Tags: android, json

i am trying to upload the image to server(POST method) by get the image from gallery,but its not upload the image to server.

**My Code**

```
browse_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);

        }
    });

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            selected_image.setText(""+get_image_name(selectedImageUri));

            kb = Double.valueOf(get_image_size(selectedImageUri))/1024;
            mb = kb/1024;

            if (mb>1) {

                Toast.makeText(Update_profile.this, "Seleced Image memory is greater than 1 MB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    // just some safety built in 
    if( uri == null ) {
        // TODO perform some logging or show user feedback
        return null;
    }

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if( cursor != null ){

        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    return uri.getPath();
}
```

**Upload image**

```
 class update_profile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    String viewbranchSuccess;
    String status,userID,username,hash;

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progressDialog = new Dialog(Update_profile.this);
        progressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        progressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
        encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Log.v("selected path", ""+selectedImagePath);


            try {

                postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hash", Constants.hash));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("avatar",encodedImage));

                String response = null;
                try {

                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://www.abc.com/api/editprofile.json",postParameters);
                String result = response.toString();

                Log.v("Result", ""+result);

                json_length = new JSONObject(result);

                jsonarray = new JSONArray("["+result+"]");


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }       
return null;
}

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

**Custom HTTP Client**

```
public class CustomHttpClient {
public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; 
private static HttpClient mHttpClient;
private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    if (mHttpClient == null) {
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    }
    return mHttpClient;
}
public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I don't know how to solve this issue,can any one know please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Are exceptions being thrown from the try-catch?

Comment: No.i didn't get any exception

Comment: Can you post the server side code?

Comment: i don't know the server side code,its an open project.

Comment: @Yugesh try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762581/how-to-take-a-photo-and-send-to-http-post-request-with-android/19762715#19762715

Comment: @AnkitPopli am try above link what you give,i put three values in the nameValuePairs but its not take those values.

Comment: @Yugesh is it throwing some error?

Comment: @AnkitPopli no but image not uploaded to server.My java code is `List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hash", Constants.hash));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("avatar", selectedImagePath));
    
    URL url;
    try {
     url = new URL("http://www.abc.com/api/editprofile.json");
     MultipartServer.postData(url, nameValuePairs);
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }`

Comment: are you getting any response from server? without any logs its difficult to debug..

Comment: @AnkitPopli in server response.it shows **HASH** parameter is missing.

Comment: @Yugesh ok.. got the problem.. the hash is being sent in body.. not in headers..

Comment: @AnkitPopli where can i sent this hash(has is a string).

Comment: @Yugesh You'll need to make changes on the server, you'll extract the hash from the body of the data being sent.