# File Upload in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to upload a file along with some other text fields from android. I keep getting this error

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly
```

However if I do an upload without the file (i.e. only text fields) it is working.
The file upload works when I do it from a webpage and hit the same servlet.

Comment: Post your relevant code

Comment: May be you have close your stream some misplace. So show your code here.

Comment: post your code and full logcat

Comment: I suspect you are running this asynchronously (in an `AsyncTask` or similar) and are simultaneously closing your InputStream in another thread.

Can you post the code where you open the stream, start the transfer, and close the stream again?

Comment: have a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762581/how-to-take-a-photo-and-send-to-http-post-request-with-android/19762715#19762715, its generic and not only for images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i'm  working for uploading files this may be useful for you and if you have any questions while implementing you can cas me.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uploadUrl);
  File file = new File(path);
  if (file.exists()) {
    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
   MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);
    if (httpPost != null) {
      httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);
      httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: I was using this code all along. I figured out my problem. I was using a library to get the file path. This library was returning me the wrong path. Hence the problem. Once I changed the library it started working.