# Uploading Multipart-form-data to php

Tags: java, php, android, forms, upload

I would like upload any data (Username, Description,..) and a photo from my Android-App to my Server (PHP-Script).

By searching for this i found a solution: [How to take a photo and send to HTTP POST request with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762581/how-to-take-a-photo-and-send-to-http-post-request-with-android)

By click on my send button, the upload-process starts and the php-script works but the $_POST -Vars are empty? Can anybody help me? My request-code:

```
[...]
case R.id.btnSend:
    String strName = tName.getText().toString();
    String strEmail = tEmail.getText().toString();
    String strDatum = tDatum.getText().toString();
    String strBeschreibung = tBeschreibung.getText().toString();        

    nvPairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sender", "AndoidApp"));
    nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", strName));
    nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", strEmail));
    nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("datum", strDatum));
    nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("beschreibung", strBeschreibung));
    nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bild", bmpUrl));

    new UploadTask().execute();
}
[...]

private class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String response = "";
        try {
            response = new MultipartServer().postData(new URL(postUrl), nvPairs);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }       
}
```

On the MultipartServer-Code i changed the line:

```
if ((avatarName = pair.getName()).equals("avatar")) {
    avatarPath = pair.getValue();
}
```

to this:

```
if ((avatarName = pair.getName()).equals("bild")) {
    avatarPath = pair.getValue();
}
```

And the Variables "bmpUrl" and "postUrl" are set correctly at an another line in my code.

Comment: `the $_POST -Vars are empty?`. That is php. But you did not show your php script. Please do. What is the return string if postData()?

Comment: In `new UploadTask().execute();` you're not passing the data.  See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for an example and specifically take note that `execute` is passed variables when called.

Comment: @Jeremy. Please don't confuse the OP. He is passing all name value pairs as parameter of the postData() call.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry for your confusion.  Do you see the scope such that those variables are in the async task in a thread-safe fashion?

Comment: Think so. I've never seen problems AsyncTask's using global (to activity) data.

Comment: @greenapps I don't guess at what others have coded that they haven't shown and I certainly don't get pretentious enough to accuse others of "confusing the OP" b/c they didn't make the unfounded assumptions I was happy to accept.

Comment: Here is the PHP-Script:

    `<?php
        echo "POST:\n";
        var_dump($_POST);
    ?>`

But the var_dump returns an empty array.

Comment: Here is the PHP-Script:

    `<?php
        echo "POST:\n";
        var_dump($_POST);
    ?>`

But the var_dump returns an empty array. The return string of postData() is the Output from PHP: ` array(0){ }`

Comment: Please add a  var_dump($_GET); and  var_dump($_REQUEST); to your php script. Please tell your setup: emulator/device server local/internet.

Comment: `nvPairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);` What is this 2 doing? You got more key value pairs then that.

Comment: var_dump($_GET) and var_dump($_REQUEST) results in an empty array; The Device i'm using is a USB-connected Samsung Galaxy Note II and the php-script lies on my webserver at www.allgäu-chasing.de

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help! I found an solution for the problem. The problem was at the Script from [How to take a photo and send to HTTP POST request with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762581/how-to-take-a-photo-and-send-to-http-post-request-with-android)

I changed it to this:

```
public class MultipartServer {

    private static final String TAG = "MultipartServer";
    private static final String crlf = "\r\n";
    private static final String twoHyphens = "--";
    private static final String boundary = "AaB03x"; //*****
    private String avatarName = null;
    private String avatarPath = null;

    public String postData(URL url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) throws IOException {

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

        FileInputStream inputStream;
        OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);

        for (NameValuePair pair : nameValuePairs) {
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(crlf);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(
                    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""
                    + URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8") 
                    + "\";" + crlf);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(crlf);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            if (pair.getName().equals("bild")) {
                avatarName = pair.getName();
                avatarPath = pair.getValue();
            }
        }

        // Write Avatar (if any)
        if (avatarName != null && avatarPath != null) {
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(crlf);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);
            dataOutputStream
                    .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""
                            + avatarName + "\";filename=\""
                            + new File(avatarPath).getName() + "\";" + crlf);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(crlf);

            inputStream = new FileInputStream(avatarPath);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = inputStream.read(data)) != -1)
                dataOutputStream.write(data, 0, read);
            inputStream.close();

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(crlf);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + crlf);
        }

        dataOutputStream.flush();
        dataOutputStream.close();

        String responseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
        Log.d(TAG, responseMessage);

        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        char[] b = new char[512];
        int read;
        while ((read = bufferedReader.read(b)) != -1) {
            response.append(b, 0, read);
        }

        connection.disconnect();
        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```