# multipart/form-data, load image(android)

Tags: java, android, post, multipartform-data

Sorry for my english. I try to use post and multipart/form-data to send an image to a server. I spend many times, try fix my code, but all to no avail. This is the example what I need to send as image:

```
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="imageName.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

This is my first version:

```
public static String executeHttpLoadImage(String url, String nameValueF, String paramValueF, String nameValueS, String paramValueS,
                                                File file, String fileName) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            String BOUNDARY= "----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C";

            HttpClient client = createHttpClient();

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(); //post
            request.setURI(new URI(url));

            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+BOUNDARY); //set header

            request.setHeader(nameValueF, paramValueF);               //set header
            request.setHeader(nameValueS, paramValueS);               //set header

            //set multipart
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,BOUNDARY,Charset.defaultCharset());
            try {

                entity.addPart("file01", new FileBody(file));
                request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", e.toString());
            }

            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+BOUNDARY);
            request.setEntity(entity);


            //set multipart

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            String result = sb.toString();
            return result;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My second version:

```
public static String executeHttpLoadImage(String url, String nameValueF, String paramValueF, String nameValueS, String paramValueS,
                                                File file, String fileName) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            String BOUNDARY= "----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C";

            HttpClient client = createHttpClient();

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(); //post
            request.setURI(new URI(url));

            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "form-data; name=image; filename=imageName.jpeg"); //set header

            request.setHeader(nameValueF, paramValueF);               //set header
            request.setHeader(nameValueS, paramValueS);               //set header

            //set multipart
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,BOUNDARY,Charset.defaultCharset());
            try {

                entity.addPart("file01", new FileBody(file));

            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", e.toString());
            }


            //set multipart

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            String result = sb.toString();
            return result;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But my all versions do not work :(

**UPD:**

I use this in asynkTask like this:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            JSONObject json = null;


            try{
                json = new JSONObject(CustomHttpClient.executeHttpLoadImage(
                        "https://example.net", "id", "123",
                        "key", "123",
                        fileName, "image1"));

                Log.e("load image", json.toString());

            }catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("Load image", e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }
```

**fileName** - its file I chose from the gallery, i get imge like this:

```
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

                    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();


                    try{
                        Bitmap myBitmap = decodeUri(selectedImage);

                        //set 
                        fileName = persistImage(myBitmap, "1123123");

                        //load image
                        new LoadImageToServer().execute();

                        imageRoom.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Image", e.toString());
                    }

//code

//method return bitmap -> file

 private File persistImage(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {
        File filesDir = context.getFilesDir();
        File imageFile = new File(filesDir, name + ".jpg");

        OutputStream os;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error writing bitmap", e.toString());
        }

        return imageFile;
    }
```

Comment: THis is the second post about the same problem. You did not change the text in any way. You are not even showing how you call these functions. Which you did in a comment in your other post. You are not explaining why there is no image content in your example. You should give much more to the point info. Also about your server. You are not telling what the server receives instead. What dioes not work exactly?

Comment: @greenapps thanks for answer, i update my qestion

Comment: You should take a look at this response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762581/how-to-take-a-photo-and-send-to-http-post-request-with-android

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the library "Retrofit" for REST. Making his http client is not the "beautiful" option.